# How View and Controller Communicate in MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a question about Model View Controller.

I get confused about how View and controller can communicate with each other.

I have a view class which takes in a model instance:

```
View v = new View(model);
```

I have also got a actionListener field in the View class and in that constructor I am passing in a model and the instance of the current class(view):

```
private ActionListener listener;
.
.
.
listener = new Controller(model,this);
```

Now in my controller class I have extended the ActionListener and passing in the model and the view class:

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener{
    public Controller(model m, View v){ 
.
.
.
```

Now my question is, can you pass a view class in the constructor of a controller class in model view controller? Reason why I am passing in the view is that I sometimes want to close the view window or want to pass in the values from a textfield. Also sometimes I want to invoke a method from the view class. Is this the right way of doing MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask 5 different people how to implement MVC and you will get 5 different answers. There are so many different ways to do it. I would read more about MVC and other design patterns such as MVP. Martin Fowler has some great articles on [GUI patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) . There is also [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/erwinvandervalk/2009/08/14/the-difference-between-model-view-viewmodel-and-other-separated-presentation-patterns/) which has great info.

To answer your question. There is nothing wrong with the controller knowing the view. The controller is the one that should be handling the user input (other wise you could consider MVP). I would create an interface and only have the controller know an interface for a view. So create something like IView and have your view realize that interface. That way you don't have a tightly coupled view and controller and you can do things like creating a mock view for testing.